# Tagging Status in the Image

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, tagging

I have a phonejs project, created for web, using html and js. I need to have a page containing a project construction plan/highrsie building plan image. There are some numbers of lots in that image, lot 1-20 for example, that will having status AVAILABLE, SOLD, BOOKED etc. I want to make the user can tag in the image the status for the corresponding lot, maybe differentiate by colour, for example RED=SOLD, GREEN=AVAILABLE, etc, and the status can be save into database. Could anyone suggest me on what is the best way/method for accomplishing this? Thanks a lot in advance.

I have already tried by using canvas. The following is my code.

HTML

```
<div data-options="dxView : { name: 'status_tagging', title: 'status_tagging' } " >
<div  data-options="dxContent : { targetPlaceholder: 'content' } " >
   <h4>Drag the status to the corresponding lot.</h4>
    <img id="available" width=32 height=32 src="images/available.png">
    <img id="booked" width=32 height=32 src="images/booked.png">
    <img id="hold" width=32 height=32 src="images/hold.png">
    <img id="reserved" width=32 height=32 src="images/reserved.png">
    <img id="sold" width=32 height=32 src="images/sold.png">
    <img id="siteplan" src="images/siteplan.jpg">
    <br>
    <canvas id="myCanvas" width=300 height=300 style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;"></canvas>
</div>
```

JavaScript

```
KioskAdminV2.status_tagging = function (params) {

var id = params.id;
var tb_prop_siteplan = new KioskAdminV2.tb_prop_siteplanViewModel();
var canvas=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
var $canvas=$("#myCanvas");
var canvasOffset=$canvas.offset();
var offsetX=canvasOffset.left;
var offsetY=canvasOffset.top;
var img=document.getElementById("siteplan");
ctx.drawImage(img,10,10);

var image1=new Image();
image1.src = "images/available.png";
var image2=new Image();
image2.src = "images/booked.png";

var $available=$("#available");
var $booked=$("#booked");
var $canvas=$("#myCanvas");

$available.draggable({
    helper:'clone'
});

$booked.draggable({
    helper:'clone'
});

// set the data payload
$available.data("image",image1); // key-value pair
$booked.data("image",image2);
$canvas.droppable({
    drop:dragDrop
});

function dragDrop(e,ui){
    var element=ui.draggable;
    var data=element.data("url");
    var x=parseInt(ui.offset.left-offsetX);
    var y=parseInt(ui.offset.top-offsetY);
    ctx.drawImage(element.data("image"),x-1,y);
}


return {
    id:id,
    tb_prop_siteplan: tb_prop_siteplan,
    canvas:canvas,
    ctx:ctx,
    $canvas:$canvas,
    canvasOffset:canvasOffset,
    offsetX:offsetX,
    offsetY:offsetY,
    img:img,
    image1:image1,
    image2:image2,
    $available:$available,
    $booked: $booked,
    dragDrop: dragDrop

};
```

};

But i got error "cannot read property of 'getContext' of null". Can anyone tell me why is this?

Answer (score 0):

You could do your project in Canvas or SVG, but...

Since your building plan is fixed in shape, you don't need them to do your project.

Just use html+css -- simpler to learn + more html+css tutorials online.

1. Cut your building plan into lots and make an image of each lot.
2. Make both a green and red shaded version of each lot.
3. Listen for mouseclick events and determine which lot the use clicked in.
4. Toggle the image for that lot from red-to-yellow-to-green representing sold-booked-available.

Comment: Thank u markE but the building plan this system will have is uploaded by the user. And may have lot of different plans. The main thing is the plan is uploaded by the user. Can this method be use?

Comment: Yes, if you just want the user to click in a lot inside a building image to apply the word "sold" or "available".  The app could add that word under the mouse.  If you want to fill an undefined lot area with a red or green color you would have to get their building images and define those areas for them (they are unlikely to have the skills required to define an area).  Good luck with your project!

Comment: Is there any other method to be used coz I am doing a project where the user will upload all their building plans, and they themselves will tag the lot whether they were SOLD/AVAILABLE/BOOKED. I had modified my question above and also attached my code that i try to use for this, using canvas. But it return error "cannot read property of 'getContext' of null". Can you tell me what is wrong? TQ

Comment: You don't need the complexity of canvas if you want to tag the lots with text (as opposed to flood-filling a lot with a color).  (1) put the user's building plan in an img element (2) create some draggable text (Sold, Available, Booked).  (3) when the user drops one of the texts save the drop x/y coordinate (4) when the user is done marking upload the url of the building plan plus the dropped texts with their drop coordinates to your server.